# Model associations clarification in Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to best do my model associations. I have 3 tables.

**players**, **teams**, **teamplayers**

my outline is that a player can belong to multiple teams. a team can have multiple players, but then in my teamplayers table I have 2 fields **teamid** and **playerid**(not counting the primary key id).

For example:

```
Player has id of 1000
team has id of 501
```

In the teamplayers table that would be stored as:

```
 team_id    player_id
  501        1000
```

so how would I design the relations **belongs_to** and **has_many** in my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this as given below :

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, :through => :team_players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :teams, :through => :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end
```

The corresponding migration might look like this:

```
class CreateTeamPlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :team_players do |t|
      t.belongs_to :player
      t.belongs_to :team
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then if you want to fetch players of a particular team, just do

```
@team = Team.first (do as per your requirement)
@team.players
```

Also, to fetch a player's teams,

```
@player = Player.first (do as per your requirement)
@player.teams
```

H2H :)-

Comment: is the corresponding migration a new ruby file?

Comment: Also does the belongs_to in the migration file set the relations?

Comment: Yes, that migration file can be used to create your tables with required relationships. Also, belongs_to will set the relations in teamplayers table.

Comment: would and rake db:migrate re-run this if i changed the migration file?

Comment: ok i was able to do that but how can i use that it a loop for html rails html? Like this? `<select id = "Plyrs" style = float:middle size = 10>
 <% team.find(1).players do |f| %>
  <option><%= f %></option>
 <% end %>
 </select>`

Comment: if you had really benefited with my answer, do mind to accept it. Also, the above one, please raise it as a seperate question describing the scenario.

Comment: I did post the one above as a separate question which has also been answered, thanks for your help and to everyone else thank you for your help as well

Answer (score 0):

Following should do:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :teams, through: :team_players
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :players, through: :team_players
end
```

Comment: yea you don't wanna camel case the model names

Comment: ok i did that and the following line in my html does not work: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.find(:all, :joins => :player, :conditions => {:teamid => @ids}), "teamid", "playerid") %>` The error that it gives is: Unable to autoload constant Player, expected C:/Sites/rails_projects/TestFFL_App/app/models/player.rb to define it

Comment: ok I am now getting the error: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Player. And i have defined as the relation controllers as the answer above. I already downgraded from rails 4.0.2 to rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

you want the has_many through association.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teamplayers
  has_many :teams, through: :teamplayers
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teamplayers
  has_many :players, through: :teamplayers
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: `has_many :teamplayers` should be replaced with `has_many :team_players`.

Comment: why is that? because the class name is teamplayer and the table is called teamplayers

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in two way:

first is:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end
```

second is:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :teamplayers
   has_many :teams, through: :teamplayers
end

class TeamPlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :player
   belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :teamplayers
   has_many :players, through: :teamplayers
end
```